# spread multiple rows into one column?

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
start<-c("123337543","123337543","68947241","68947241")
stop<-c("123338361","123338361","68954945","68954945")
snp<-c("chr8_94225198_G_A_b38","chr8_94225198_G_A_b38","chr3_123338356_C_A_b38","chr3_123338356_C_A_b38")
tissue<-c("Thyroid","Esophagus","Esophagus","Thyroid")
df<-data.frame(start,stop,snp,tissue)
```

Is there a way of 'merging' the rows into one column?
eg the result would look like:

```
start<-c("123337543","123337543")
stop<-c("123338361","123338361")
snp<-c("chr8_94225198_G_A_b38","chr3_123338356_C_A_b38")
tissue<-c("Thyroid,Esophagus","Thyroid,Esophagus")
df<-data.frame(start,stop,snp,tissue)
```

I have tried dplyr spread and group_by but I think I am running into problems as I don't have unique values?

Comment: `aggregate(tissue~start + stop + snp, df, toString)`

Comment: amazing! What a great function!